# Probability test question

Tags: probability

My son got this question on a test, and I am trying to go over the answers with him. But he can not explain to me how he got the answer. He answered $49/100$

> **Question**
>
> A box contains $5$ strawberry candies, $3$ banana candies, and $2$ orange candies. If Braden selects $2$ candies at random from this box, without replacement, what is the probability that both candies are not banana?
>
> 1 - $1/15$
>
> 2 - $9/100$
>
> 3 - $7/15$
>
> 4 - $49/100$

Please help me so I can understand the steps needed and he and I can sit down and go over it together.

Comment: 7/10*6/9 = 42/90 = 7/15

Comment: I would press your son to explain how he arrived at his answer. If he can’t, he’s likely just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Method I:  The probability that the first one is a non-banana is $\frac 7{10}$ as there are $10$ candies in total and $7$ of those are non-bananas.

Having removed a non-banana from the total there are now $9$ candies left, of which $6$ are non-bananas.  Thus the probability that the second one is a non-banana, conditioned on the first one also not being a banana, is $\frac 69=\frac 23$.

As you need both events to occur the probability is the product $$\frac 7{10}\times \frac 23=\frac {14}{30}=\boxed {\frac 7{15}}$$

Method II: there are $\binom {10}2=45$ ways to choose $2$ candies with no restriction.  There are $\binom {7}2=21$ ways to choose $2$ non-banana candies.  Thus the answer is $$\frac {21}{45}=\boxed {\frac 7{15}}$$

Note:  Your son answered the question correctly  if Braden were choosing WITH replacement.  In that case the probability would be $$\frac 7{10}\times \frac 7{10}=\frac {49}{100}$$  but of course that is a different problem.  One way to stress the difference is to imagine that $8$ candies were drawn.  WITH replacement, the probability that they are all non-bananas is $\left( \frac 7{10}\right)^8$.  WITHOUT replacement it is obviously $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The box contains 10 candies in total.  7 of the candies are not banana.  So for the first candy selection there are $\frac{7}{10}$ possibilities and for the second candy selection there are $\frac{6}{9}$ possibilities (provided that they chose a non-banana candy in their first selection).  Since the candies are chosed randomly without replacement, then we just need to multiply these two individual probabilities together.  So we get $\frac{7 \cdot 6}{10 \cdot 9} = \frac{42}{90} = \frac{7}{15}$

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 7/15. The key words are "without replacement." This means that you select the first candy, do not put it back and then select the second candy. The probability that the first candy selected is not banana is 7/10 since there are 10 candies total, 7 of which are not banana. Now imagine setting aside that first candy that is not banana. Now there are 9 candies left, 6 of which are not banana. So the probability that the second candy is not banana (given that the first is not banana) is 6/9 = 2/3. Now we multiply these probabilities: (7/10)(2/3) = 7/15.

If the question said "with replacement" instead, the correct answer would have been 49/100 because "with replacement" means that after looking at the first candy selected you put it back before selecting the second. In that case the probability of not getting a banana on each selection is 7/10 and (7/10)(7/10) = 49/100.